# How Can I Use rabbitmqctl to Connect to a Remotely Hosted RabbitMQ Server?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using a hosted RabbitMQ solution (provided by VMware), where I'm assigned an individual RabbitMQ queue, along with a username / password. I'd like to see some of my queue's stats using the `rabbitmqctl` command, but I can't find documentation anywhere which shows how to use `rabbitmqctl` on a remote host.

Here's what I get from my host:

> amqp://user:pass@blah.rabbitmq.com:31278/myqueue

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I used to use rabbitmqctl a lot because I was stuck with a sysadmin who refused to install the RabbitMQ management plugins. But really, nowadays with version 2.8.4 of the server, just install the plugins. This gives you not only a web management GUI but a nice CLI that does allow you to talk to remote servers as well as local ones.

I haven't touched rabbitmqctl in months since the management plugins became available.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a promising situation.
The URL above contains a nonstandard port (not 5672), so it is very likely that the service is tailored to give you ONLY what was paid for and nothing more.
You would need

- to know the erlang cookie installed on the remote host - they will not give that to you, as it would let you fully manage the service
- the inter-node communication port used by the remote host (https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports) which may be guessed based on the AMQP port, but it could also be nonstandard.

What is much more likely possible is to upgrade your plan to include access to the management plugin. Then you will need

- the remote port where the management functions are accessible (15672 unless nonstandard)
- your user tagged as 'management' to allow read access to the management information